# Web Crypto API maturity for JavaScript RSA encryption?

Tags: javascript, rsa, web-crypto-api

We have been using a JavaScript crypto API to do RSA encryption in the browser. I know all the criticisms on encryption in JavaScript but we have evaluated pros and cons of the solution and the risks are acceptable for us.

In the past we used pidcrypt but now the project is abandoned so I was looking for a standard library and I have seen the Web Crypto API.

The question is how much is it mature the standard especially on mobile devices?

Comment: This may be of use: https://caniuse.com/#feat=cryptography

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for the web crypto API is allright, but not perfect. According to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=cryptography) it got 91.5% support:

- You'll need to use prefixes for some older browsers, and deal with some inconsistencies in the IE 11 version of the API.
- Older versions of IE than 11 have no support at all. But that's only a 0.3% of global usage.
- Your big problems are two mobile browsers - Opera Mini (2.3%) and the Android browser (0.8%). They have no support. However, usage of these might vary across the world. Opera Mini, for instance, is big in the developing world but not so much elsewhere.

What's important here is that you need to completely disable your application (or at least the sensitive parts) if the crypto API is not supported. Falling back on something terrible such as `Math.random` is not an option. Telling 8.5% of your users they can't use your site might off course cause some PR problems...

I'd say you need to have a very special use case for this to be motivated. But you seem to be familiar with the criticism, so I will not reiterate that. Just make sure your problem isn't already solved by the correct use of HTTPS.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Sure we use HTTPS and we could evaluate to fall back to another crypto lib if there is not support for Web Crypto API. I must tell you that the application is used by a restricted population so the range of browser is not so extended. This justify the choices.

Comment: @robob From where does that other JavaScript crypto library get secure random numbers? That would be my main concern about using something other than the Web Crypto API.

Comment: I would like to use Web Crypto API to avoid other libs to avoid PRNG not secure, the fall back is only if the detected browser does not support the Web Crypto API.

Comment: @robob Encryption with predictable random numbers is more like obfuscation than encryption.

Comment: I agree with but better than nothing...